# RXJS : Why do observers who subscribe after the value is emitted also recieve the value?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import {  take } from 'rxjs/operators'

const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(4),
);
source$.subscribe(value => console.log(`Observer 1: ${value}`));

setTimeout(() => {
  source$.subscribe(value => console.log(`Observer 3: ${value}`));
}, 3000);
```

So, here the Observer 3 subscribes after a 3 second delay.

By that time the values `0, 1` has already been emitted.

However, this is the output shown.

```
Observer 3: 0
Observer 3: 1
Observer 3: 2
Observer 3: 3
```

How is the observer getting values that were emitted before it subscribed to the observable?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of observables in rxjs - hot and cold, interval is a cold observable.

Cold observables are observables where the data producer is created by the observable itself. For example, observables created using the `of`, `from`, `range`, `interval` and `timer` operators will be cold. The data is created from within the observable itself, and there truly is not data being produced until the observable is subscribed to.

When a cold observable has multiple subscribers, the whole data stream is re-emitted for each subscriber. Each subscriber becomes independent and gets its own stream of data

You can see the behavior in action with the following example:

```
const source$ = interval(1000).pipe(
  take(4),
  tap((v) => console.log(v)),
);

setTimeout(() => {
  source$.subscribe(value => console.log(`Observer 3: ${value}`));
}, 3000);
```

no value is emitted until you subscribe to source$!